# encrypting a file and storing the passwoed hash and salt in the same file

Tags: python, cryptography

am trying to store the password hash and the password salt in the same file that i've encrypted
i tried to write them in the beginning of the file but when i checked if the they were the same before and after wrting it to the file and the answer was they weren't
any help please

this is the function which encrypte the file

```
    def encrypte(self):
        global pic_path,getOpenFileName
        from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
        import base64
        from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
        password_provided =  self.pass_entry1.text() 
        pass_hash=hashlib.sha256(password_provided.encode('utf-8'))
        password = password_provided.encode()  # Convert to type bytes
        salt =bytes(os.urandom(16))  
        print("salt: "+str(salt))
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
               algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
               length=32,
               salt=salt,
               iterations=100000,
               backend=default_backend()
               )
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))  
        file = open(pic_path,'rb+')
        fdata=file.read()
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted = f.encrypt(fdata)  # Encrypt the bytes. The returning object is of type bytes
        file.close()
        try:
                os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"/encrypted")
        except:
                pass
        pic_path=os.getcwd()+"/encrypted/"+name
        fileencrypted=open(os.path.splitext(pic_path)[0]+'.cod','ab+')
        fileencrypted.write(salt)
        fileencrypted.write(pass_hash.digest())
        fileencrypted.write(encrypted)
        fileencrypted.close()
        self.error_label.setText("file encrypted scessfully")
```

and this is the function which i used to check if the salt is the same

```
   def decrypte(self):
        file= open(filename,'rb')
        salt= file.read(16)
        print("file salt:"+str(salt))
```

Comment: You're opening the output file in mode "ab+".  If the file already exists, you're appending to it rather than overwriting it.  I think you just want "wb".

Comment: @FrankYellin i am opening it in ab+ mode to be able apend the salt and the passhash to the file

Comment: If the file exists before you execute this code, your code will open the file and start appending to the end of it.   The original contents will still be there at the beginning. 
 From the way I'm reading your code, you are creating a new ouptut file, and then writing its salt, its hash digest, and its encrypted form.  This is what "wb" does.

Comment: but when i use wb mode and use write() function again the content will be overwritten isn't it ?

Comment: That is incorrect.  "w" vs "a" only controls what happens when you first open the file.  After that, all writes happen consecutively.

Comment: oh i didn't know that thanks a lot 
i've tried it and it works

Comment: by the way is this a valid output and is it okay if the (b') isn't removed ?
`salt: b'\xacu\xd8\xa0?\x02\xdc\xc9\xc8\xce\xc4\xabw\xeb\xd0\\' `